# How to print values from dropdown?

Tags: java, reactjs, selenium, react-select

Can someone explain how to print/ read all the options from dropdown which are build using select-react library. I have referred to link below:
https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/856
 Or this is something not possible with selenium webdriver.

[attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKbZW.png)

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Try using [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) html parser if possible, it is easier than selenium if the website doesn't require javascript